# Why are only single digit integer inputs working and not double digit integers?

Tags: python-3.x, input, integer

I'm trying to write a function which asks for a number and then prints a line. It works flawlessly for single digits, but once I use two digits, my if/elif statement only sees the first digit and not both digits together.

I created a sample function in python3 and ran a test. I tried changing the str to int and also just input() and nothing worked.

```
>>> def test():
...     out = str(input('Choice: '))
...     if out[0] == '1':
...             print('Test1 Worked')
...     elif out[0] == '2':
...             print('Test2 Worked')
...     elif out[0] == '10':
...             print('Test10 Worked')
... 
>>> test()
Choice: 1
Test1 Worked
>>> test()
Choice: 2
Test2 Worked
>>> test()
Choice: 10
Test1 Worked
```

On the last run of test() my Choice is 10 and I'm expecting the output to be Test 10 Worked, yet it says Test1 Worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `out` is a string and you are taking the first element `out[0]` which is only the first character. Hence `out[0] == '10'[0] == '1'`.

You will have to do `out[:2] == '10'` or, since it's easy to mess that up, it's better to use `if out.startswith('10')`. If you know the whole string will just be a number, it's safe to do `out == '10'`.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to check for value of out instead of out[0] since out[0] will check for the first character of your input

```
def test():
  out = str(input('Choice: '))
  if out == '1':
    print('Test1 Worked')
  elif out == '2':
    print('Test2 Worked')
  elif out == '10':
   print('Test10 Worked')
```

Comment: Agreed..  I went with removing all the [0] entries and I'm now right as rain.